# Jquery assign value to select2 dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have dropdowns that are being appended dynamically on a page. However, I could not assign the value to the select2. Anyone can help me with this?

Below is what I have try to do to assign the data to select2, but still cannot. Where am I missing??

```
1. $('select.row-item').eq(index).val(item.itemID);
2. $('.row-item:eq("' + index + '")').val('"' + item.itemID + '"')
3. var $row = $(html)
   a. $row.find("row.item option[value=" + item.itemID + "]").prop("selected", true);
   b. $row.find('select .row-item').val(item.itemID).trigger('change');
```

```js
$(function() {
  var data = data1
  var html = '';
  html += '<thead><tr>';
  html += '<th>Item</th>';
  html += '<th>Description</th>';
  html += '<th>Qty</th>';
  html += '<th>Total</th>';
  html += '</tr></thead>';
  html += '<tbody class="acc_table">';
  data.forEach((item, index) => {
    html += '<tr class="acc-row">';
    html += '<td><select class="row-item"><option label="Choose One"> </option><option value="10">ITEM 1</option><option value="20">ITEM 2</option></select></td>';
    html += '<td><input class="row-desc" type="text" value="' + item.itemName + '"></td>';
    html += '<td><input class="row-qty" type="text" onkeyup="onlyDecimal(this)" value="' + item.itemQty + '"></td>';
    html += '<td><input class="row-totalamount" type="text" value="' + item.totalAmount + '" disabled></td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    //at here I assign the data to select2
    $('select.row-item').eq(index).val(item.itemID);
  });
  html += '</tbody>';
  $('.item tbody').empty();
  $('.item').append(html);
  $('.row-item:last').select2();
  $('.item').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "info": false,
    "searching": false,
  });
})

const data1 = [{
    "itemID": "10",
    "itemName": "Item 1",
    "itemQty": "1",
    "totalAmount": "50.00"
  },
  {
    "itemID": "20",
    "itemName": "Item 2",
    "itemQty": "5",
    "totalAmount": "150.00"
  }
]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>


<table class="item">
```

Comment: `$row.find('select .row-item').val(item.itemID).trigger('change');` would work, but without the space `$row.find('select.row-item')`.   With [tag:select2] you need to call `.trigger("change")` to have select2 update

Comment: As you're building the HTML, it would be easier to add `selected` to the option you want as you build the HTML.

Comment: @freedomn-m Hi, I have try your answer without the space but the data still does not display. Here my latest js fiddle with ur answer. [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8shdv1gn/)

Comment: I also try add the selected option `$(".row-item option[value='"+item.itemID+"']").prop("selected", true)` also cannot.

Answer (score 0):

On closer look, your line:

```
var $row = $(html);
```

`$row` is not used later on, so `$row...whatever` has no effect.  You keep building the html and later do `$('.item').append(html);`.

So changing the `select` value within `$row` has no effect because `$row` is not appended, only the unchanged `html` variable.

As you're building HTML, you can add `selected` directly to the html:

```
html += '<option value="10"' + (item.itemID == 10 ? "selected" : "") + '>ITEM 1</option>'
html += '<option value="20"' + (item.itemID == 20 ? "selected" : "") + '>ITEM 2</option>'
```

---

Alternatively, if the html build can't be changed (or prefer not to, to keep it cleaner), add the itemID has a data-value and then use code later

```
html += '<select class="row-item" data-itemid="' + item.itemID + '">'
```

and then use jquery to set the .val(value) based on `.data(itemid")`:

```
$('.item').append(html);
$('select.row-item').each(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).data("itemid"));
    $(this).select2();
});
```

Note: you only need `.trigger("change")` *after* you've converted the `select` to a [select2](/questions/tagged/select2) - if it's not a select2 yet, then no need to call `.trigger("change")` (unless, of course, you have some other code that relies on this change and needs to run during initialisation, but would be better to explicitly call that rather than raise an event).

Comment: but my option value is dynamic and it may more than 100 options. I just put an example for my fiddle. So I can't assign `selected` directly to the html. Is there any other way to assign?

Comment: But you're building html, with 100+ options?  I honestly don't see the difference.  But regardless:  can you add a `data-itemid` to the `select` (not the option as put above, now updated)